# SQL Server Force Results of Select Statement to Output Window Before End of Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to force the results of a Select Statement to the Output window in SQL Server Management Studio before the end of the entire script is reached?

I have one select query that executes quickly, and one that takes a while to execute.  I would like to look at the results from the first query while the second is running.

My issue is that the same variables are used in both queries and if a "GO" statement is used, the variables will be lost.  Example below.

```
declare @MyVar int
set @MyVar = 1

-- Query with short execution time
select  *
from    MyTable t
where   t.Column = @MyVar

GO -- @MyVar is lost

-- Query with long execution time
select  *
from    MyOtherTable o
where   o.Column = @MyVar -- @MyVar no longer exists
```

Comment: I've never had this issue. I see result sets as they are generated in SSMS.

Comment: Ah right I see. `select * from master..spt_values waitfor delay '01:00' ` returns 2474 rows but it seems there are 32 still in the buffer that don't get flushed. `select top 1 * from master..spt_values waitfor delay '01:00' ` doesn't return any rows immediately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use raiseerror , which will cause the buffer to flush :

```
RAISERROR( 'Just to print everything',0,1) WITH NOWAIT
```

you can put this between the queries.

Comment: Bingo. `select * from master..spt_values RAISERROR( 'Just to print everything',0,1) WITH NOWAIT waitfor delay '01:00' ` works for me.

Comment: Works Great.  Thanks!  More Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you could store your variable in a temp table.

```
create table #MyTable (MyVar int)
insert into #MyTable (MyVar) values (1)

-- Query with short execution time
select  *
from    MyTable t
where   t.Column = (select MyVar from #MyTable)

GO -- #MyTable is preserved

-- Query with long execution time
select  *
from    MyOtherTable o
where   o.Column = (select MyVar from #MyTable)
```

Comment: This is how I am currently solving the issue.  I'm looking for a better solution, but this does work.